# Power Supply Issues in Cold Temperatures

Tags: power-supply, power, temperature

We use a relatively old 12V 5A power supply in an unheated room to drive motors for an astronomical observatory. When the temperature gets close to 0C, the power supply voltage drops to a few volts. Warming the power supply up by a few degrees fixes the issue.

This is proving very hard to debug because I cannot reproduce the issue under room temperature. How would you approach this problem? What components are most likely the cause of this failure? Or would you expect multiple components to fail, making an easy fix less likely?

Comment: Some kinds of capacitors have much lower capacitance at lower temps.

Comment: Why bother even trying, you can pick up a new one a lot cheaper than it cost you for the time it took you to type this question.

Comment: Temperatures do affect component values and semiconductor behavior. It's not uncommon to see variation of a factor of 2 in semiconductor currents for every \$10^\circ\textrm{C}\$ change in temperature. It may be a design issue for your power supply. Or it may be something else. Is there a reason why keeping the old supply is important? Could you consider the idea of buying one for testing and see if the problem can be resolved that way?

Comment: I would expect component parameter change with temperature to be steady, you are describing a sort of threshold effect. I have twice in my 40 year career had this sort of problem, and it's been a dry joint or broken track where thermal movement moves it in and out of contact. With the supply powered, at high or low temperature, poke various components, leads and bits of the board with an insulated stick, and see if anything changes. You may be lucky. Note that a PC power supply can often be had for free, and gives 12v at a shedload of amps, may have to draw a little 5v power to make it happy.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks for this suggestion. I've resoldered a few connections on the PCB that looked murky. I'm still waiting for some arctic temperatures to test it, but it seems to be working much more reliably in somewhat cold temperatures so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Troubleshooting something like that. The change *to* a few volts is more than I would expect even if the e-caps were completely open.

Inspect visually for a bad solder joint or cracked component. Pay particular attention to the control circuitry unless you believe the ripple voltage at the output is increasing. Look also for evidence of heating in other areas and evidence of water damage if that could be a possibility.

If you don't have a schematic, make one. It doesn't have to be perfect at this point, just identify the blocks and where they interface to each other.

Instrument the power supply (eg. bring out the feedback voltage divider voltage) and either put it in an environmental chamber and cool it, or leave it outside with a device to measure and log the voltage. Examine the logs for clues.

---

If the power supply can be replaced by a switching power supply (does not have to be especially low noise, nor does it have to have high current surge capability), consider just buying an open-frame supply from a reputable maker.

Motors typically require large surge current at start-up and if you try to replace an old transformer-rectifier linear regulated supply with a switching supply  you may need to use one that is significantly higher in current capability than the nominal rating of your existing supply.

Comment: Even a cheap PC power supply will give you a lot of amps at 12 volts.

Comment: @RobertEndl Thanks. That's a simple idea worth trying out. But I wonder if it might not be the best solution for driving the motors...

Comment: Resoldering a few joints indeed solved the issue! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

An example of older model obsolete e-caps shows the T_min['C] rises with working voltage (WV) due to a difference in electrical dielectric properties.

- Operating temperature

  - 6 WV DC to 100 WV DC ... -40 °C to +85 °C
  - 101 WV DC to 475 WV DC -20 °C to +85 °C
  - 500 WV DC and higher ...  +20 °C to +65 °C

Electrolytics have the highest failure rates of all parts in a PSU with symptoms of reducing C and rising ESR, which together with a temperature sensitivity for reducing C would cause the charge capacity to diminish.

It would be more cost-effective to replace the PSU with a 350W or 500W surplus ATX supply with a Power enable jumper to ground.